# How to refactor a class that is serialized in .NET?

Tags: .net, serialization, refactoring, versioning, binaryformatter

I have a C# class that is serialized to disk by the [BinaryFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter(v=VS.100).aspx), such as this example:

```
// Version 3.0
[Serializable]
public class Person
{
    public string FullName;

    [OptionalField(VersionAdded=2)]
    public string NickName;
    [OptionalField(VersionAdded=2)]
    public DateTime BirthDate;

    [OptionalField(VersionAdded=3)]
    public int Weight;
}
```

Later, I want to refactor this class by one or more of the following
- Change its name
- Change its namespace
- Move to another assembly

As far as I can tell, the binary file can only be de-serialized if a class with the exact same name, namespace and assembly name is available.

How do I work around this?
Is it possible to map the de-serialization to a different class name, namespace and assembly without breaking [Version Tolerant Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229752(VS.80).aspx)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some research I realized that the BinaryFormatter does support everything I was looking for.

A BinaryFormatter can use *surrogates* to

> 1. Provides the ability to serialize a type that was not originally designed to be serialized.
> 2. Provides a way to map one version of a type to another version of another type.

One can also map deserialization from type A to type B (different class name, namespace and/or assembly name) by using *SerializationBinder*.

As far as I can tell, this makes it possible to refactor classes that are serialized and to maintain backwards compatibility when making breaking changes that is not supported by versioning alone.

Reference: http://www.diranieh.com/NETSerialization/BinarySerialization.htm

Edit: On a side note, refactoring fields (name or type) is still a pain, as discussed in [Renaming fields then deserializing in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942343/renaming-fields-then-deserializing-in-c). I am currently looking into protobuf-net to better solve this in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the [`ISerializable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable.aspx) interface and override [`GetObjectData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable.getobjectdata.aspx) to provide your own deserialization. I have not tried, but you should be able to deserialize your old object "manually".

Comment: So you mean Person should implement ISerializable and GetObjectData()? How will the de-serializer know that this exact Person class should be used, when it has a different name, namespace and/or assembly? Can I somehow tell the de-serializer which class to use?